# cannot save a document to couchbase using reactive approach

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-webflux, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to persist some date generated by a scheduler and then read them through a rest endpoint in a stream manner. I have a very simple model, a `Feed` holding only uuid and some text. I also have a repository that extends `ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Feed, String>`.

Persisting works when I use the `CouchbaseRepository<Feed, String>`.
here is my `Feed`:

```
@Document
public class Feed {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String text;
    ...
```

and the repository:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "feed")
public interface FeedRepository  extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Feed, String> {
}
```

as well as the scheduler:

```
    ....
    @Autowired
    private FeedRepository feedRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void generate(){
        feedRepository.save(new Feed(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    ...
```

here is my endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private FeedRepository feedRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/get/feed/live", produces = "text/event-stream")
    public Flux<Feed> getLiveFeeds(){
        return feedRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

when I call the endpoint I get this:

```
Tue Apr 09 15:12:02 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
View feed/all does not exist.
com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException: View feed/all does not exist.
    at com.couchbase.client.java.view.ViewQueryResponseMapper$BuildViewResult.call(ViewQueryResponseMapper.java:211)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.view.ViewQueryResponseMapper$BuildViewResult.call(ViewQueryResponseMapper.java:185)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:113)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:281)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.defer(Flux.java:805)
    org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrapperConverters$RxJava1ObservableToFluxConverter.convert(ReactiveWrapperConverters.java:682)
Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
    |_  Flux.defer â‡¢ org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrapperConverters$RxJava1ObservableToFluxConverter.convert(ReactiveWrapperConverters.java:682)
    |_  Flux.map â‡¢ org.springframework.http.codec.ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.encode(ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.java:119)
    |_  Mono.doOnError â‡¢ org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractServerHttpResponse.writeAndFlushWith(AbstractServerHttpResponse.java:186)
    |_  Mono.flatMap â‡¢ org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handleResult$5(DispatcherHandler.java:175)
    |_  Mono.onErrorResume â‡¢ org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResult(DispatcherHandler.java:175)
    |_  Mono.flatMap â‡¢ org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handle(DispatcherHandler.java:152)
    |_  Mono.defer â‡¢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.doAfterSuccessOrError â‡¢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.reactive.HttpTraceWebFilter.filter(HttpTraceWebFilter.java:99)
    |_  Mono.flatMap â‡¢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.reactive.HttpTraceWebFilter.filter(HttpTraceWebFilter.java:82)
    |_  Mono.defer â‡¢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer â‡¢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.doOnSuccess â‡¢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:84)
    |_  Mono.doOnError â‡¢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:84)
    |_  Mono.compose â‡¢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:76)
    |_  Mono.defer â‡¢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)

Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
    ... 16 more
```

1. Why is the date not persited when using the reactive repository
2. Why I cannot fetch at least the data persisted already using a regular couchbase repository?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT 1:
there were three things that were wrong/missing in order to persist:

1. `@EnableReactiveCouchbaseRepositories` was missing (pointed out in one of the answers)
2. The Config did not extend `AbstractReactiveCouchbaseConfiguration` but a regular one
   3.The call  `feedRepository.save(new Feed(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))` was missing `.subscribe()` at the end.

Now the persisting part works. 
Still have problem with fetching.

edit 2

have just found out this debug message in the log while calling the endpoint:
`2019-04-10 16:27:06.467 DEBUG 11172 --- [-computations-3] c.c.client.java.view.ViewRetryHandler    : Design document not found, error is {"errors":[{"error":"not_found","reason":"Design document _design/feed not found"}`

Comment: Can you share the code somewhere? because everything looks ok to me.

Comment: here you go https://github.com/mooras/reactiveDemo

Comment: just  answered, let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to enable the reactive repositories using the @EnableReactiveCouchbaseRepositories annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableReactiveCouchbaseRepositories
public class ReactiveDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.reactiverepository.usage

Comment: I added the annotation but no new items appear in the bucket (there are only the initial 49 I've managed to save with the regular `CouchbaseRepository`)

Comment: the doc says that the couchbase config class should extend the `AbstractReactiveCouchbaseConfiguration` which wasn't the case before. Changing it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your FeedRepository interface is missing the name of the view that is used for performing the search.

Do try with the below view name:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "feed", viewName = "all")
public interface FeedRepository  extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Feed, String> {
}
```

For me it worked after adding the view name.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but hopefully this could help others.
In reactive programming you need to subscribe to your publishers, otherwise, the flow of information won't start. In you example `feedRepository.save(***)` is never executed because you need something like `feedRepository.save(**).subscribe()`.

For the second question, as you are requesting all items you need to specify a view like `{item}/all`, for newer Couchbase versions, you could specify a PrimaryKey as a required index to get all items.